# Tableau total average vs average per location

Tags: excel, average, tableau-api, calculated-field

Uploaded workbook on [public tableau](https://public.tableau.com/profile/sonihal#!/vizhome/NumericBusinessRatings/AvgperLocation)

I understand how to chart average per location in Tableau, i.e. create calculated field

```
AVG([Rating])
```

And then plot this vs the location.

But now, I am looking for average of ALL ratings, regardless of location, so I created calculated field

```
WINDOW_AVG([Avg_Rating], First(),Last())
```

If you see tab `Grand Average`, it equals 3.704, which I expect, calculated in EXCEL.

But if you see tab `Avg per Location` and hover over the bars, you will see

```
Tot_Avg = 3.848
```

How on Earth did this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because with that `WINDOW_AVG()`, you are not excluding Location from the aggregation. `WINDOW_AVG()` is looking at all the rows in your partition. You've set up your rows by dragging Location and Avg_Rating into your view. Your partition looks like this:

```
| Location            | Avg_Rating |
+---------------------+------------+
| Belfrance Chocolate |  4.55      |
| Boston Tea Party    |  3.73      |
| Eat at Joe's        |  3.13      |
| ...                 |  ...       |  
+---------------------+------------+
```

So `WINDOW_AVG()` is calculating the average of all of those Avg_Ratings in your partition.

If you want to exclude Location from the aggregation, an intuitive way to do that is to use `EXCLUDE`.  Try this:

```
{ EXCLUDE [Location (Loc)] : AVG([Rating]) }
```

This will exclude Location from the level of detail, so that your partition will include every row (for just this calculation), instead of an aggregation for each Location, and you'll average the original ratings instead of averaging the averages per Location.